# Run time error 9 : subscript out of range while retrieving data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, oledbconnection

I get this error very often, trying to figure out a solution for this.

The statement that gets highlighted when this error message observed is

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("US**** PIRExposure_G2_4 tConrac"). _
        OLEDBConnection
```

Please let me know if I need to post my entire VBA code here. I am trying to import a row from a SQL Server database into Excel by running a pre-recorded macro after deleting the range of cells where previously executed macro result is displayed.

Comment: Please post your VBA code, it will help us find a solution to your problem :)

Comment: The code is all about retrieving data from database using a stored procedure. I suspect, deleting the range area from excel is causing the issue but not aware of the resolution.

Comment: I would guess that, at the time the command is being run, `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("US**** PIRExposure_G2_4 tConrac")` does not exist.  Either the connection isn't there, or ActiveWorkbook is not pointing to where you expect it to be.  It is usually better to explicitly address a workbook/worksheet/range/etc, instead of depending on it being Active. (Sometimes there's no choice).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for your suggestion, it worked. Could you up vote the question if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found that this was due to the lack of connection that exists or gets deleted when I was trying to clear the range where the result is displayed prior.

How did I debug ?

Checked if connection exists or not by going to Ribbon - Data - Connection and check if the connection exists there.